# background: url(images/2.png) doesn't work in style.css

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

background: url(images/2.png) in file style.css (located in web-app/static/styles/style.css ) cannot load picture 2.png located in web-app/static/images/2.png .I'm using spring framework

Comment: An image URL in a stylesheet is relative to the URL of the stylesheet, so you'll want to use an absolute URL or use a relative path that can find the image such as `../images/2.png`

Answer (score 2):

That implies that you image is in an images folder within your styles folder i.e. styles -> images -> 2.png

I suggest trying ../images/2.png which goes back a folder, if your images folder is inside the static folder i.e. static -> images -> 2.png

Answer (score 0):

you do image located in web-app/static/styles/images/2.png

or

background: url(http://localhost/web-app/static/images/2.png)

where is your image location?

Comment: my image location is in web-app/static/images/2.png

Comment: you is try : background: url("../images/2.png");

So out of a folder

Comment: browser(your page) on right click -> Check items -> network.  See and edit location your image

Comment: @SamiKobbi and in respect to ur web-app where is the stylesheet located